# Может ли socket обрабатывать post и get запросы?

Tags: python, сокет

Остался только велосипед.

Можно ли обрабатывать запросы с помощью  `socket'а`, и как используя `socket.send` на сервере чтобы сформировать `html` для отображения в браузере клиента?

Comment: Не совсем понятен вопрос

Comment: прошу прощения. сервер через модуль socket слушает 127.0.0.1:80, при открытии этого ip нужно в браузере отобразить передаваемую сервером html - страницу. И вопрос, как сформировать данные передаваемые через socket.send(data)?

Comment: через сокеты конечно можно сделать `get/post` запросы. хоть `html` хоть другое можно отправлять. Но лучше велосипеда пользоваться готовыми типа `apache`. можете `apache` использовать как `listener` и соединить к своей программе. так как если будете велосипед делать, трудно будет многопоточноть реализовать.

Comment: можно реализовать `http` сервер поверх `socket`, например, [`http.server` написан поверх `sockerserver`, который в свою очереь написан поверх сокетов](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.5/Lib/http/server.py#l144). Или (более реалистичный пример) можно посмотреть на [`gunicorn`](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/). В чём цель данного упражнения?

Comment: @jfs, Сегодня уже было несколько абсолютно аналогичных вопросов, но с использованием C# и С++. Поэтому я предполагаю, что это - представители некой учебной группы, которым дали массовое задание вроде "напишите на любом языке свою простенькую реализацию протокола http, при этом используя только сокеты"..  Разбираться же никому не охото, поэтому пишут сюда в надежде что это задание сделают за них. Как-то так )

Comment: @SaidolimDjuraev: многопоточность тривиально реализуется (по сравнению с разбором http вручную), например,  поверх `threading` модуля см., [David Beazley - Python Concurrency From the Ground Up: LIVE! - PyCon 2015](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MCs5OvhV9S4)

Comment: @Sergey Rufanov, Нет же, не задание. Разобраться самому охота)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не хватает теоретических знаний о работе сети. Сеть организована в виде вложенных друг в друга слоев разного уровня. Любой высокоуровневый протокол (а здесь неявно подразумевается HTTP) использует более низкоуровневые протоколы, обеспечивающие вещи, которыми не должны заниматься высокоуровневые протоколы (например, HTTP существует поверх TCP, и последний контролирует целостность данных).

Как это относится к вопросу? Дело в том, что используя сокеты, вам, скорее всего, придется едва ли не побайтово работать с HTTP, выделяя запросы из потока TCP, в то время как есть более высокоуровневые библиотеки. Вы, безусловно, можетет использовать сокет для этих целей - и "под капотом" он *всегда* будет использоваться - однако вам, скорее всего, нужно что-то более высокоуровневое, а если и пилить реализацию - то вам все равно придется это делить на различные уровни.

Comment: 1. Python socket API также как и в любом языке очень похоже на C socket API 2. сокеты находятся выше уровня TCP-пакетов (абстрация сокетов -- это *поток* байт): вот [пример кода для клиента и сервера](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example)

Comment: ответ нашел здесь https://andreymal.org/socket3/. вопрос как строку b"text" изменить под python не принимающий префикс b?

Comment: @Drjabaka: не вижу, где там http-сервер реализован.

Comment: @jfs, посмотрите внимательнее, перед "TCP-клиент" в спойлере

Comment: @Drjabaka: да, действительно, если нажать на кнопочку "показать код", duh, то присутствует некая простейшая (с ошибками) реализация.

Comment: @Etki, во всех языках программирования сокеты работают с протоколами TCP и UDP. Просто потому что это зависит не столько от языка, сколько от ОС - а все современные ОС предоставляют сокеты именно что 4го уровня (ну, есть конечно еще "сырые" сокеты - но их очень редко используют).